# Can a use a variable with printf() format

Tags: c++, c, format, printf

Hi i want to format the output of my binary search tree in C/C++ without hard coding it every time.I saw people using (%*, int) but it didnt work for me.

```
printf("%* %-s\n", format, String")  format = format*2
```

`printf("%* %-s\n", format, String")`

I want a output like this

`String
             String`

Answer (score 4):

`printf` formats can use variable arguments for the width and precision parameters:

```
printf("%*s\n", width, str);
```

will output the string right aligned on `width` characters, with leading spaces.
If the string is longer than `width` characters, it will not be truncated.  If you want left alignment with trailing spaces, add the `-` option and use `"%-*s\n"`.

If you want the string to be aligned and truncated, use both width and precision arguments this way:

```
printf("%*.*s\n", width, width, str);
```